# Extinct block in index

Tags: stale-block

I am working on a blockchain parser. I first parse the header index to know where the data is located in the .blk files. And then I parse the blk files in the right order. (I use the data from my full node)

However I noticed that I am including an extinct block (see [Single tx included in two different blocks](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90667/single-tx-included-in-two-different-blocks)) while parsing (and blockchain.info seems to do the same).

How is that possible? How to get the actual block?

While parsing the index I check the condition `NStatus&(blockHaveData|blockHaveUndo) != 0` before including the block, is that enough?

A validated block has `NStatus = 0x9d` whereas the extinct block has `NStatus = 0x8b`.

There does not seem to be another valid version of the extinct block in my index (height 525890)

Edit: The error comes from my validation condition `NStatus&(blockHaveData|blockHaveUndo) != 0`. As a temporary fix when a given height is referenced twice in the index I keep the on with the largest `NStatus`.